# Группировка и подсчет количества по нескольким колонкам в dataframe pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

столкнулся с проблемой группировки датафрейма по нескольким столбцам. Пытаюсь методом groupby сгруппировать столбцы, но он дропает строки с пустым значением

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('data.xlsx'))
df = df.groupby(['Имя'])['число'].value_counts()
```

```
df
Out[64]: 
Имя        число      
Ваня       любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Ваня 4     любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Виталя     любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Виталя254  любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Женя       любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Женя3      любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Катя       любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Катя1      любимое        2
           Не любимое     1
Name: число, dtype: int64
```

Нужный результат должен быть такой, чтобы считалось количество значений двух столбцов "знчение1" и "значение2":

```
df
Out[64]: 
Имя        число      
Ваня       любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Ваня 4     любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Виталя     любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Виталя254  любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Женя       любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Женя3      любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Катя       любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Катя1      любимое        4
           Не любимое     1
Name: число, dtype: int64
```

[Ссылка](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/3Dwf2yro73gBAQ) на таблицу

Comment: Вопрос написан непонятно, но можете попробовать задать ключ dropna=False у value_counts

Comment: Я сейчас понял что он не дропает пустые ячейки, а попросту не берет столбец "значение2". Как сделать чтобы учитывались и считались оба столбца?

Comment: ваш код вообще не знает ничего про колонки значения, он считает варианты заполнения число. И я не понимаю, что вы собственно хотите получить. что такое 4/1 у вани, если их всего 3 и только одно пустое значение?

Comment: Указать эти колонки вместо 'число'? Только там две квадратных скобки нужно будет уже

Comment: @splash58 если посмотреть таблицу, то у Вани 4 любимых числа и одно не любимое(исходя из данных обоих столбцов "значение")

Comment: Так вот ты какой - северный олень :)

Comment: По итогу мне нужна таблица где будет указано количество значений любимых и не любимых чисел, исходя из обоих столбцов "значение1" и "значение2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, это оно :)

```
df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df1 = df.groupby(['Имя', 'число'])[['значение1','значение2']].count().sum(axis=1)
print(df1)

Имя        число      
Ваня       Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
Ваня 4     Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
Виталя     Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
Виталя254  Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
Женя       Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
Женя3      Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
Катя       Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
Катя1      Не любимое     1
           любимое        4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Да, действительно:) все оказалось просто) Спасибо)